# Regex - Append after group, keep content in-between

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need some help working around special cases, in my own compiler.

The idea is to turn

```
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) {
@media screen and (min-width:1088px) and (max-width:1279px) {
```

into

```
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) { #test-id
@media screen and (min-width:1088px) and (max-width:1279px) { #test-id
```

(appending #test-id after the opening bracked)

I can see that the two stakes in the ground are "@media" and "{".
With that in mind, what are possible regex solutions to preseve the code inside "@media" (...) "{" and append a "#test-id"?

Raw regex for match and replace will help.

Cheers!

Comment: Not sure what language you're incorporating your regex in, but something like this would work in Python: `re.sub(r"(.+?\{)", r"\1 #test-id", your_string)`. Example: https://regex101.com/r/pqq2L1/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the expression:

```
(^@media[^{]+{)
```

- `(` Capturing group.
- `^` Assert position beginning of line.
- `@media` Match literal substring.
- `[^{]+` Match anything other than `{`.
- `{` Match a `{`.
- `)` Close capturing group.

Replacing with:

```
\1 #test-id
```

You can try the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/EnzEmA/3).

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Some languages such as Erlang want a "&" instead of a "\1". This gave me the idea I needed.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, in certain languages you may also use `$1`.

Comment: @JonRiel Actually, the `&` usually means "replace with entire match", therefore it is not exactly the same as replacing with the contents of the capture group. From the Erlang re docs too: *The replacement string can contain the special character &, which inserts the whole matching expression in the result*

Comment: @JonRiel You can find more information [at this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacebackref.html).